# Ball and urn method (counting problems)

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> How many ordered triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers exist with the property that $abc = 500$?

Since, $500 = 2^2 5^3$

I believe this can be solved using [Ball and Urn](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Ball-and-urn)

let $a = 2^{x_1}5^{y_1}$ and then the subscripts increase by $1$ for $b, c$.

There is:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2$$

$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 3$$

We count each seperately.

There are 3 "bins," $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Then what are the objects? Im confused?

Comment: I think you want to say you have three bins, say $b_1,b_2,b_3$ with in total $x_1+x_2+x_3$ blue balls and $y_1+y_2+y_3$ red balls.

Comment: The objects, for each prime, are the exponents associated with that prime for each of the three factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the same as the ball and urn method:

We can distribute the two factors of $2$ among $a,b,c$ using the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) method: each arrangement corresponds to an arrangement of $\{\star,\star,|,|\}$. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to arrange these.

We can distribute the three factors of $5$ among $a,b,c$ using the stars and bars method: each arrangement corresponds to an arrangement of $\{\star,\star,\star,|,|\}$. There are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to arrange these.

Comment: (+1), what does this mean:

$${⋆,⋆,|,|}$$

Comment: ALSO, arent there $3$ factors of $2$? $2^0, 2^1, 2^2$?

Comment: @Amad27 The 'stars' represent 'balls', the 'bars' represent 'walls'.  Thus counting the permutations of those four symbols counts the distinct ways to distribute two identical balls into three distinct bins.  And this maps onto ways to enumerate the exponents of $2$ that factor $a,b,c$; as $0, 1,$ or $2$ 'balls' in each 'bin', for a total of $2$.

Comment: @Amad27: I have added a link to the "stars and bars" method. This method counts the number of ways to distribute the stars into bins divided by the bars (therefore, the number of bins is the number of bars plus one).

Comment: @Amad27: there are two factors of $2$ to be distributed among $a,b,c$ and three factors of $5$ to be distributed among $a,b,c$.

Comment: @robjohn. Isnt $2^0 = 1$ considered a factor?

Comment: @Amad27: look at the stars and bars link. The arrangement $|\star|\star$ for $2$ represents $1\cdot2\cdot2$ and $\star\star||\star$ for $5$ represents $25\cdot1\cdot5$. This gives the factorization of $500=25\cdot2\cdot10$

Comment: @robjohn, I just looked at the page. I am specifically looking at "Theorem 1." Fig.2 "two bars give rise to three bins containing $4, 1$ and $2$ objects. Then lets see:

$$ |⋆|⋆$$ 

1 bar, object, 1 bar, object. So how many bins and objects are there? Also, when you said it represents $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$, where did you see that in the page?

Comment: @Amad27: the variables are arranged $a|b|c$ and the location of each star represents one of the two factors of $2$. Thus, $|\star|\star$ would represent $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=2$. For the three factors of $5$, $\star\star||\star$ represents $a=25$, $b=1$, $c=5$.

Comment: So $0, 1, 1$ considering the factors of $2$?

Comment: Then:

$$ \{⋆,⋆,|,|\}$$

Represents $a = 2, b= 0, c = 0$?

Comment: Each arrangement of $\{\star,\star,|,|\}$ uniquely represents the location of each of the two factors of $2$. Each arrangement of $\{\star,\star,\star,|,|\}$ uniquely represents the location of each of the three factors of $5$

Comment: $\{\star,\star,|,|\}$ is a collection without order. $\star\star||$ would represent $4\cdot1\cdot1$ ($a=4,b=1,c=1$).

Comment: I think I got it. And then you use the binomial coefficient to determine how many possible arrangements can be done for $2^1$ right?

Comment: Yes, it counts the number of ways to distribute the two factors of $2$ among $a,b,c$. The other counts the number of ways to distribute the three factors of $5$ among $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on robjohn's answer.

The 'bins' (or urns) are the factors $a, b, c$.

The number of 'balls' are counted by the exponents of $2$. Since $500= 2^25^3$ there are two 'balls' to distribute among the three bins ($a,b,c$) to determine what exponent of $2$ each might receive.

$$\begin{array}{lll}a & b & c \\ \hline
2^2 & 2^0 & 2^0 & \ast\ast \vert\vert
\\ 2^1 & 2^1 & 2^0  & \ast\vert\ast \vert
\\ 2^1 & 2^0 & 2^1 & \ast\vert\vert\ast
\\ 2^0 & 2^2 & 2^0 & \vert\ast\ast\vert
\\ 2^0 & 2^1 & 2^1 & \vert\ast\vert\ast
\\ 2^0 & 2^0 & 2^2 & \vert\vert\ast\ast
\end{array}\qquad \dbinom{2+2}{2,2}=\dfrac{4!}{2!2!} 6$$

And similarly we count the ways the exponents of $5$ may be assigned by counting the permutations of $3$ stars and $2$ bars.$$\dbinom{3+2}{3,2} = \dfrac{5!}{3!2!}=10$$

Comment: So. $$\{* * | |   \}$$ There are 4 items Let the bar represent $2^0$ and the star represent $2^1$. The ways to arrange is: $$\binom{4}{2}$$? Then, consider:

$$\{*** | |    \}$$ which is: $5^3, 5^0, 5^0$.  There are 5 objects. Let $* = 5^1$ and let $| = 5^0$. The ways to arrange the star is $$\binom{5}{3}$$

??

Comment: No, @Amad27 , The bars don't represent exponent counts, they are separators indicating to which factor the exponents belong - the 'walls' of the three boxes, $a\vert b\vert c$.

Comment: Then why is it $5$ choose $3$? If there are only $3$ tangible ***? How about this: lets have $*$ and $+$. So then:

$$\{*** | + | + |  \}$$

Where $+$ represents empty and $*$ represents $2^1$? @Graham, how about this?

Comment: @Amad27 The walls are tangible enough, and you don't need something to represent `empty` when having nothing between the walls represents `empty`.  What would $\{\ast+\vert+\ast\vert\ast\}$ represent?